# How do i go about programming GUI desktop apps with Java or C++?

Tags: java, c++

this is my first post here. I'm new here and i'm also kindda new to programming.
So i learned a little bit of c to get a grounding on the concept of programming then jumped to c++ for a bit and now i seem to be understanding it pretty good and doing Java now.
I'm confused on what languuage is best for creating desktop apps(Especially for mordern programming concepts)?
How do i start projects like music player program, picture viewer and stuff?
And i'm from nigeria, there's not much of a good programming environment even for computer science majors in college, it mostly depends on the students. So please some friendly advice for a newbie programmer!

Comment: This question is not well suited for our Q&A format on stack overflow, but the short is answer is that apps get written in all sorts of languages, including c++ and java, as well as many more. They all have different approaches to building a GUI-driven application.

Comment: There's no absolutely better language. Both Java and C++ are good for creating desktop apps. They both have many libraries, large communities, and plenty of online resources to learn more.

Comment: For Java, use the Swing framework and libraries to create desktop GUI applications that can be run on MacOS, Windows, and Linux without modification to your code. You can also port your GUI application to Android because it has a similar GUI library. If you want to use C++, there are cross-OS libraries such as GTK+, Qt, and wxWidgets. If you are targeting a specific operating system (e.g. you want to write only for Windows), then use use an OS-specific language. On Windows, use C#. On MacOS, use Objective-C (or Swift, which was introduced recently).

Comment: There is a possibility to use both C++ and Java for programming desktop applications.  Write some libraries in C++ and call them from Java.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For java, you use a WYSIWYG tool for UI's. I know netbeans has one. for C++, don't ask me.

If you look for compatibility accross platforms choose java above C++, because java offers it and C++ doesn't. (I'm not saying it's the best)

Comment: C++ is fairly good for platform independence. There are also good libraries (such as qt) for GUI development. There are cases in which java is indeed the preferable choice, I'm not denying that.

Comment: didn't know about that one. I always learned to go with java over C++ if you wanted cross platform compatibility

Comment: C++ is not a platform-dependent language.